# where should I pop a UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I know that for a modal view controller the recommended way of dismissing it is using the delegate protocol design-pattern. Does the same apply when popping a UINavigationController?

Comment: perfect. that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that the typical way of popping a view in a UINavigationController stack is via the back button in the navigation bar, which the UINavigationController provides for you. There's no need to code for that.

However, if you've got a view which doesn't display the navigation bar (e.g. it sets `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO`) then yes, you should define a delegate on your UIViewController subclass and make the delegate responsible for dismissing the view.

The rationale behind this is the same as for modal view controllers; the view controller shouldn't have to know about how it was presented.